# Need formatting help for isEqualToString args

Tags: objective-c

Code sample:

```
NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%@", [self.answers valueForKey:idVor]];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"%@",nameVor];

NSLog(@"%@", title);
NSLog(@"%@", message);

if([title isEqualToString:message])
    NSLog(@"equal");
```

The vars title and message never respond to the if statement even though they contain the same string.

I ran NSLogs for these to see what was contained in each string var.
I got the following output:

```
f[Session started at 2009-09-21 17:27:56 -0500.]
2009-09-21 17:28:00.256 pickerReview[2394:20b] (
    Amedee
)


2009-09-21 17:28:00.257 pickerReview[2394:20b] Amedee
```

I guess it's not equal because the NSString title var has parentheses around it... Is there a way to format this so that it satisfies the expression in the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're asking self.answers (an NSArray) for its `valueForKey:@"whatever"` — this doesn't return a string, but an array made up of the result of asking each object in the array for that key value. NSArray's `description` method (what gets printed when you NSLog it) is the contents of the array surrounded by parentheses. So you're comparing a string to an array containing a string.

Comment: I was trying to format the outputs to boldface with double asterisks, not sure what happened.  Anyways... the title var is a string contained in an NSDictionary  value and the other is a string object inside an array.  

They were both input simply as @"Amedee".  Why does the dictionary value output with parentheses?

Comment: I see now that I'm thinking two things are equal when they aren't.  What is a possible solution to put the [self.answers valueForkey: idVor] into a format that IS equal to my NSString object?

Comment: Well, you have an array containing a string, so you need to get the string out of it.

Comment: I understand that I need to get the string out of the array, and I'm still asking how to do that.  I've tried several things...I've tried naming a variable, I've tried, init'ing a whole new string, but I still get the format of parentheses first (still getting the array returned)
NSString *idToCompare = ??? [self.answers valueForKey: idVor];

Comment: You ask the array for an object: `[array objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly.  I was getting so caught up with the mindset that the object in the array was a string and ignoring the fact that the method I was using to get that object was returning an array.... lesson learned.